# What is the difference between Point.OrientationMode ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL and Point.OrientationMode INITIALIZED_TO_IDENTITY?

Tags: android, arcore

After I read the following document, the information I get is an orientation mode of the feature point is `ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL` if it is on textured surfaces, otherwise it is `INITIALIZED_TO_IDENTITY`.
But I expect the feature point to be detected because it is on textured surfaces, so I'm a bit confused about the detailed differences between the two orientation modes.

In addition, when we hit these feature points, are we not able to determine in advance what their orientation mode is?

---

*Attempt to estimate the normal of the surface centered around the hit test. Surface normal estimation is most likely to succeed on textured surfaces and with camera motion.*

> public static final Point.OrientationMode **ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL**
>   Point orientation will follow the behavior described in getHitPose().`
>
> public static final Point.OrientationMode **INITIALIZED_TO_IDENTITY**
>   Point orientation is initialized to identity but may adjust slightly over time.

Answer (score 3):

When the Pose of a Point reflects the normal of detected surface, its OrientationMode is ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL. Otherwise its INTIALIZED_TO_IDENTITY, and with this, I assume you cannot tell which direction the detected surface is facing.

I was able to tell the difference when I modified the sample app code so that it drops the figurine not only on ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL, but also INTIALIZED_TO_IDENTITY. With the latter, the figurine's head was always perpendicular to the ground, not following the normal of detected surface.

You can get more detail here:
getHitPose()
https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/HitResult